# Calling animation in custom view's Kotlin class from Java activity class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-animation, android-custom-view

I have a Java Activity class that contains a custom view which is written in Kotlin

```
@BindView(R.id.icon)
Icon icon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    icon.showIcon();
}
```

And the custom view class:

```
fun showIcon() {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
    rotate()
}

fun rotate() {
    ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 360f).apply {
        interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        startDelay = 1000
        duration = 1400
        addUpdateListener {
            val value = it.animatedValue as Float
            squatIV.rotation = value
            Timber.d(iconIV.rotation.toString())
        }
        start()
    }
```

Binding work normally, I can see the icon on the activity when created. Even the animation runs because it's logging the rotation value of the Image View of the component. But on screen, the animation is not playing.

Is there a specific reason for that? Have you ever encounter this issue?

Update: Below you can see the dummy activity page and the custom view needs to be animate rotation. After some backend checks, custom view becomes visible and rotate animation triggers.

[image: dummy page]

Comment: It can be easier to resolve problem if I see your custom view.  I think problem is not difficult

Comment: Hi @sergkk , I have added the dummy representation of page

Comment: It can be million reason appearance of problem. So it is difficult to say right answer. Please provide me code (it can be privacy). May be you don't use <squatIV.rotation> ?

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
fun rotate() {
    ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 360f).apply {
        interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        startDelay = 1000
        duration = 1400
        addUpdateListener {
            val value = it.animatedValue as Float
            squatIV.rotation = value
            Timber.d(iconIV.rotation.toString())

            invalidate() // must be!
            requestLayout() // check if works without it
        }
        start()
    }
```

Comment: have added both `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` still not showing that animation playing on screen but updatelistener triggered :(

Comment: It can be easier to resolve problem if I see your custom view.